# cannot recognize the variable created just above the code in pycharm

Tags: python, indexing, pycharm, ide

## enviroment

Pycharm version:  2023.1.2.
OS: mac Big Sur, 11.7.7.

## problem

the problem is , it stop recognize the variables

for example
As shown in the picture below.
it is `pass` now, but it continues to be recognized as `passs` that I typed a few seconds ago.
[image]

Or, as shown in the figure below, 'dataset_dir' variable already declared above, but next line, it cannot recognize `dataset_dir`
[image]
[image]

## temporary solution

Restarting pycharm , it worked. but after a few minutes, this happens again.
how can i fixed it?

thank you

Comment: SO is not a bug reporting service. Report bugs at youtrack.jetbrains.com.